# How do I write an inline multiline powershell script in an Azure Pipelines PowerShell task?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

The yaml schema for a [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) allows you to select targetType: 'inline' and  define a script in the script: input.

But what is the correct format for writing a script with more than one line?

The docs don't specify how, and using a pipe on line one (like is specified for the Command Line task) does not work.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the pipe character (the [literal Block Scalar Indicator](https://yaml-multiline.info)) to define a multi-line block of text with newline characters such as your inline script; for example like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      Write-Host "Hello world"
      Write-Host "Hullo clouds"
      Write-Host "Hullo sky"
```

Comment: Is it possible to do inline with the new shorthand task `pwsh`?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to just use the powershell task like this:

```
# Job definition etc
steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host A
      Write-Host B
      Write-Host C
  - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      # The rest of this task is omitted.
```

If you use `powershell` instead of `task: PowerShell@2` the target type defaults to `inline` and you don't need to set it again.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to [chain PowerShell command using semicolon](https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell). So in effect writing several commands on one line, separated by semicolon.

(Be aware of the [5000 characters line limit](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6509) in Azure Pipelines.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.