# While scanning a simple key, could not find expected ':'. Syntax error in azure-pipeline.yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to execute an azure pipeline. It was executing fine. But when I added a task to conditionally check pom.xml file exists then only I need to execute that particular task, but it fails

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Post text of code and error messages.

Comment: Sure thanks...will do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script needs to be more indented:

```
- bash: |
    if [ -f Maven pom.xml ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FILEEXISTS]true"
    fi
- task: Maven@3
  etc
```

See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58555822/174843